# Getting button input

Tags: php

Why does this not work. I have look at many sites and this works I look long time. Fine no no.

Edited code to this it echo pressed when I havent even pressed the button

```
<form method='POST' name="form1" action="index.php">

        Username: <input name="username"><br>
        Password: <input name="password"><br>


        <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'click me'>



    </form> 

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

            echo "Pressed button";



}



        ?>
```

Comment: I copied this verbatim in a blank PHP file and it works fine. You should close your `<form>` tag though, and the password input needs to be `type="password"`.

Comment: Its working... I just copied your code and ran in a php file.

Comment: It Does not work it echos pressed when i havent clicked the button.....

Answer (score 2):

You missed the tag `<form></form>`. Therefore it is not working

Answer (score 1):

you need to add form tag and in action tag of form give your php page name. Here is index.php but you need to specify your own script name.

```
     <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
    Username: <input name="username"><br>
    Password: <input name="password"><br>


    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'click me'>
    </form>


    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        echo "Pressed button";


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need summat like

```
<form method="post" action="myscript.php">
```

etc

Comment: I'm not sure whether it needs an `action` to be valid HTML, but it will post quite happily to self without that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running even without closing form tag. But below is the formal way to use form.

```
<form method='post' action="">
    Username: <input name="username"><br>
    Password: <input name="password"><br>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'click me'>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "Pressed button";
}
?>
```